# Using INCLUDE in Indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing, include

I have a query on indexes I could not find a confirmation on (possibly due to bad wording).

I have a table T, with columns A, B & C. If I were to create an index on column A, that includes column B, I am given to understand that this is ideal for a query that filters/groups/sorts on A, and select B.

However, for other columns (example select column C), does it work like a regular index on column A without the includes?

Would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question points to difference between covered and non-covered queries. There are quite a few issues to this problem - I would advise reading [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) article. Query execution plan is chosen after considering a few conditions, so there is no straight away answer to your question.

Comment: Very interesting article. But I still not sure what that means for this situation.

If you are not reading the lookup keys of the include index, is the read performance equal to that of the index without include?

Comment: You mean if the included columns slow down the index seek even if you do not use them? All indexes are organized in pages, so if you include a lot of columns in a non-clustered index, you can fit less keys in one page. That means you need to read more pages so it has a negative impact on performance (of course only if sql decides to use the index).